# The function of 'of' in this sentence: visualization is of far more importance

Tags: prepositions

Personally, I think it comes down  to indicating that visualization is something that has much more importance", but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: 'To be of importance' means 'to be important', and trying to work out the meaning of 'of' in it is unprofitable. The expression is not invariant; 'be of [far] greater / equal / immense ... importance' are also idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the locution "is of" is to be taken here as meaning "is **characteristic of matters**" (far more important), "is **from the sort of the** (far more important) **matters**" ; therefore, the clause amounts to saying "visualization is far more important". There is no nice rendering for the preposition, as you can see, those used for explanation being wordy, unpleasantly indirect.